# Why graphql query is not working in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

[image: Second react error]In my react project I used a query to search github users data. The query is as follows:

```
const GET_USER = (user) => `
{
  user(login: "${user}") {
    name
    login
    avatarUrl
    company
    gists{
     totalCount
   }
   following{
      totalCount
    }
    followers(last: 5){
      edges{
            node{
                id
            name
            avatarUrl
        }
      }
    }
    repositories(last: 5){
      edges{
        node{
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

If I update the query by just adding a single field called `email` in `followers` the react app stops working:

```
followers(last: 5){
      edges{
            node{
            id
            name
            avatarUrl
            email
        }
      }
    }
```

The same happens if I add data about the organizations in the query, like this:

```
 organizations(last: 5){
      edges{
        node{
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
```

But when I perform the same query in this link: [https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/] it works.

My react project is in the link: [https://github.com/rvmelo/react-tech6-final-project]. The query is in the `App.js` file which is inside the `src` folder.

[image: First react error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stops working because the user might not have such information.

I cloned your repo and added the code

```
<div>email:{user.following.email}</div>
```

and it did stopped working, then I added a fallback

```
<div>email:{user.following.email || ""}</div>
```

And it worked.

You might wanna check those info before rendering, something like

```
{user && user.following && user.following.email &&
  (<div>email:{user.following.email}</div>)
}
```

Same thing with the `organizations`

```
<p>
  {user && user.organizations &&
    <div>Organization name:{user.organizations.name}</div>
  }
</p>
```

As for `followers`(**UPDATED**)

```
const Followers = ({ followers }) => (
<div>

  <strong>Followers updated for SO:</strong>

  <ul>
    {followers.edges.map(follower => (
    <li key={follower.node.id}>
      <img src={follower.node.avatarUrl}/>
      <div>
        {follower && follower.node && follower.node.name && (
        <div>Name:{follower.node.name}</div>) }
      </div>
      <div>
        {follower && follower.node && follower.node.email && (
        <div>Email:{follower.node.email}</div>) }
      </div>
    </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
);
```

Screenshot of my profile. One follower with email and another without.
[image]

I went ahead and forked your repo, [here's my repo](https://github.com/trinaldi/react-tech6-final-project) cloned from your question's [one](https://github.com/rvmelo/react-tech6-final-project)
Make sure your token has the permissions. In the heat of the moment I gave full access to my key. Check yours!

Comment: but the problem is not with `user.following`. It is with `followers.node`. I did like this: `{followers && followers.node && followers.node.email &&(<div>email:` `{followers.node.email}</div>) }` and it is still not working

Comment: It seems to be working. I'd change the name to `follower` once inside the `map` function to prevent conflict. Also, where are you using the code? I added the full function just in case

Comment: I did like you did but I just added the email field and didn't work... I have the file so you can see my update: [https://github.com/rvmelo/github-search/blob/master/App-example.js]

Comment: I just updated my post with the errors I am getting after updating the code like you asked

Comment: That's another issue, but I updated my code. I can't reproduce it, tried empty user, typing anything.. nothing. I even tried building instead of running the dev code

Comment: did you download and tested all files of my project or just copy and paste the App.js?

Comment: As I said, I cloned your repo. Just forked and still works....check your permissions, it's not the code. I also created a PR

Comment: I solved the problem! Like you said it was my personal access token that didn't give me permission to access some of the user data

Comment: Nice! If I helped you, please consider an upvote and mark as correct.